# Hydro Indigo interoperability

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have one system running ROS Hydro and another system running ROS Indigo, will nodes started on one of these systems be able to interact with nodes from the other (presuming the ROS_MASTER_URI is set correctly)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195673/hydro-indigo-interoperability/) by [engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20554/engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general yes, as long as the message definitions have not changed. It's not recommended, and should be heavily tested before being relied upon.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0